# Why are images not being shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am kind of new to web development and the whole html, css, js thing, but I dare say I am a competent programmer, so I should at least have an idea about what is not working on my code. But this is not the case and I am reaching a state of angry frustration I wouldn't like to stay in.

My objective is to create a whole online course in the same fashion of a power point presentation: clickable objects that make things appear and lead to some other pages; and animations of images appearing in order.

I have not had any issues with the previous "slides" I have transcripted to a web page, but the last one is giving me headaches.
My page consists mainly of images included via the `<img>` tag, all of them with a proper `id` and one or more `class` values (`class="class1 class2"`). Positioned with a `position: absolute;` style I place them where I want them to be. 
Next up is the animations, and here is how I handle it:

When the document finishes loading, this is, `<body class="contentBody" onload=...>` a method is called: `myLocalInit();` and it handles the animations using jQuery functions. Here is the whole code about it:

```
function myLocalInit(){
        disablePNButtons();
        hideAll('.part');
        lowerClass('.animar',50);
        slideUpAll();
    }
function slideUpAll(){
        $(".identifica").animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400);
        setTimeout(slideUpRest(),400);
}
function slideUpRest(){
        $(".identifica").animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400, function(){$('#preguntas').animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400, function(){ $('#hogar').animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400, function(){ $('#negocio').animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400, function(){ $('#holabank').animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400, function(){ $('#agrobank').animate({
            top: '-=50px',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400 function(){ $('#vr').animate({
            opacity: '1'
        }, 400)})})})})})});
}
function hideAll(class1){
        $(class1).css('opacity','0');
}

function lowerClass(class1,height){
        $(class1).css('top', '+='+height+'px');
}
function disablePNButtons(){
        UDUTU_API.gblPreviousButton.btnEnabled(false);
        UDUTU_API.gblNextButton.btnEnabled(false);
}
```

And the `<body>` looks like this in the end: `<body class="contentBody" onload="myLocalInit();">`

Then, when the page is loaded none of the methods inside `myLocalInit()` take effect, which is weird. BUT IT GETS WEIRDER! If I take out the methods from `myLocalInit()` and place them in the `onload` event (`<body class="contentBody" onload="disablePNButtons();hideAll('.part');lowerClass('.animar',50);slideUpAll();">`, they take effect up to `slideUpAll()` (I found this out via boring `alert` debugging).

I seriously have no idea of what is wrong with this particular page, I have done similar programming with the previous 7 pages and it worked well. Please, PLEASE! I beg of you all, gurus, please enlighten me on why this is not working T_T

Comment: Once thing, surely not related but: `setTimeout(slideUpRest(),400);` should be `setTimeout(slideUpRest,400);`. Now regarding your issue, you'd have better to provide online link replicating your issue. BTW, any error in console?

Comment: Heard that! Will follow the advice in the future but, as you said, it was not really related :(
Now that you say it (did not think about checking the console) it says that `slideUpAll` is not defined wtf?

Comment: I would gladly provide the link. I only know of jsFiddle but there seems to be a difficulty with uploading images...

Comment: `slideUpAll is not defined` Is it defined on global scope? Provide more context regarding your posted code. Are these methods wrapped inside other method/function? Are they included after the document is ready? Etc...

Comment: It very well should be defined, as they all are defined in the same scope. Inside the `<head>` there is a `<script> </script>` space which content is the previously posted code. Hence: they are not wrapped inside other method/function and not included after the document is ready, or so I think :/

Answer (score 1):

This might/might not solve your problem. Hard to pinpoint exact solution without debugging your code. And just reading your question doesnt make me think of any obvious issues. So I can provide a few good practices instead which could solve the problem and also make your code more dependable.

Please put your functions within a document ready block:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    // All your functions

    myLocalInit();
});
```

And then move the script tag from header to the end (just within the closing `</body>` tag.

That makes javascript non blocking, and also load only once the DOM is ready.

the next thing you could do is, also call the `myLocalInit();` at the end of the document ready block as shown above and remove it from body.onload. This will still run once the DOM is loaded.

Please let me know if these changes solved the problem.

Comment: Will follow your advices, thanks a lot for them! You are all being helpful in one way or another, even though the problem still remains ^^' (I am posting the solution right now, since I located the cause hehe)

Comment: Glad to know you found out what the issue is :), also moving your Javascript out to a file and including that as the script src is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I do that with the frequently and unchanging js pieces of code my different pages share, but there are some lines of code I would like to keep easily readable from page to page (I will leave the company soon) and thus make the maintenance easier for the poor soul that comes after me. And I just find it easier to follow if the animation sequences for each page is defined in said page instead of in a different external file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess what, I apparently missed a comma `,` inside the insidious code that manages the sequencial animation. The last callback function is not separated from the `400` parameter T_T

A whole morning for this alone... Thanks a lot for all of you who aided me and gave useful advice :)